# left side of MatDialog displaying inside sidebar how can I show Dialog over the sidebar

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have implemented `MatDialog` using Angular Material. When I open Dialog, left side of it hiding inside sidebar menus.

code in `DashboardComponent`

```
function lastSeenDevice(content) {
  
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {
    width: '80%',
    height:'80%',
    position: 'relative',
    data: { name: this.name, animal: this.city }
  });
}
```

code in `MyDialogComponent`

```
<div md-dialog-content>
     <button class="close" mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">
        <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </button>
    
    <p>What's your favorite city?</p>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Favorite City</mat-label>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.city">
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button id="matbuttonClose" mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
</div>
```

This is how my Dialog looks like. How can I fix this ?

[image]

Comment: do you want user to perform any action on sidebar while dilaog is open?

Comment: @shashanksharma - Probably not.

Comment: actually side bar has some z-index( distance from surface in z direction) value,and dialog also have that, in your case i think side bar's z-index is greater then dialog.overriding it will help you, if you want more help just create a stackblitz example i would love to make change in that.